# Sort bars according to y-value

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a dataset with two variables:

- `district`: factor w/ 26 levels (A, B, C, D etc.)
- `type`: "x", "o" (factor)

Now I'd like to plot a stacked barplot: One bar for each year.

```
ggplot(aes(x = district, fill=type), data=dat) + geom_bar()
```

My problem is, that the bars should be in ascending order (of the total of each district). Like this:

```
  |
  |  x
  |  x
  |  x  x
n |  o  x  x
  |  o  o  o
  |  o  o  o  x
  |  o  o  o  o 
  _______________
     A  C  G  B …
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a reprex for your data:

```
district <- sample(LETTERS, 1000, replace = TRUE)
xo <- c("x","o")
type <- sample(xo, 1000, replace = TRUE)
```

Here is your `df`. You need to create a `count` column that you can order your districts by.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(district, type)) %>%
  group_by(district) %>%
  mutate(count = n())
```

Within your `aes` argument, you can specify `reorder` district, by descending count:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(district, -count), fill=type)) +
  geom_bar()
```

And if you don't want to alter your `df` by grouping or adding a count variable, you can do this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(district) %>%
  mutate(count = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(district, -count), fill=type)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If your data.frame is purely two columns with the levels, then do:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(111)
df = data.frame(district=sample(LETTERS[1:4],100,replace=TRUE),
type=sample(c("x","o"),100,replace=TRUE))

head(df)

  district type
1        B    x
2        C    o
3        D    x
4        C    x
5        C    x
6        A    x

ggplot(df,aes(x=reorder(district,district,function(i)-length(i)),fill=type)) + 
geom_bar() + xlab("district")
```

[image]

Brief explanation, `reorder()` can be used to refactor one variable according to another, and it also allows for a function to be applied. In this situation, we just need to count the number of each level in district, so `length()` will work. The second `district` is just a dummy